# What activities may one carry out on a Standard Visitor visa?

Tags: standard-visitor-visas

I am planning to visit the UK to meet my husband. This is my first trip to the UK. I also wish to take the International English Language Testing System examination in the UK during my stay.

Can I apply for a Standard Visitor visa in this case?

Comment: See [Appendix 3 of the visitor rules](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules#visitors-appendix-3-permitted-activities-for-all-visitors-except-transit-visitors) for the activities permitted on a standard visitor visa.

Comment: Yes, but you need to explain why you're not sitting IELTS locally or they will get upset.

Comment: @GayotFow if the visitor can justify a visa based solely on her visit to her spouse, can she also sit IELTS during the visit?  In other words, would it be fraudulent to apply without mentioning the exam, with the plan to take it elsewhere if the visa is denied?

Comment: @phoog, the British Council can be absolutely trusted to tell UKVI.

Comment: @GayotFow That doesn't seem to answer my question. Does it matter whether the British Council tells UKVI?  Suppose someone has received a visa to visit her spouse in the UK.  During the trip, the person also attends a business conference.  Is that fraud?  Is the answer different if the plan to attend the business conference was made after the visa was granted?  Is the answer different if, instead of a business conference, the person arranges to take an English language exam?

Comment: @phoog, not sure I follow. Perhaps your question would be better put to the OP.  Do you see IELTS listed in the permitted activities?

Comment: @GayotFow is the list of permitted activities exclusive?

Comment: @phoog do you mean exhaustive?

Answer (score 3):

According to the rules laid out in [Appendix V](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules#visitors-appendix-3-permitted-activities-for-all-visitors-except-transit-visitors):

> Study
>
> Visitors may carry out the following study:
>
> (a) educational exchanges or visits with a UK state or independent school; or
>
> (b) a maximum of 30 days study, provided that the main purpose of the visit is not to study

So you should be fine taking an IELTS exam, as long as visiting your husband is the main purpose of the trip.